# This is driving me crazy, is there any REAL solution to getting an AR9285 WiFi card working properly?

Tags: networking, drivers

I have Xubuntu 14.04.4 and have tried every trick in the book and I still have intermittent/slow internet connections, even though I'm connected with a good signal at a good speed, and able to ping websites effortlessly through the terminal.  I did the rfkill unblock all, changed IPV6 settings, tried (and failed) to get ndiswrapper working, turned off hardware encryption, and looked for updated drivers.  Considering it's is such a widespread issue, why is there still no fix for this bug?  I know that one of the main issues is that my connection gets DEAUTH'd and has to reauthorize, and acts as if I'm connected to dialup even though I'm showing a 56Mbs connection.

Someone please give me an answer that doesn't refer to past solutions as I've tried every one I can find.  I've noticed many people have this issue and never got answers or the solutions didn't help them.  Will provide any info needed to delve deeper into this problem.

Comment: You could always get an [Edimax micro USB WiFi adapter](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003MTTJOY)

Answer (score 0):

The last time I had connectivity issues, it was due to a rootkit.  Try going through Software Center and installing rkhunter and chkrootkit.  Once I got rid of the rootkit, my connection speed was back to normal.

Comment: I've had the issues since a clean install, and I'm not sure how I'd get a rootkit anyway.  If there are any issues, I'll just wipe it and start fresh again because I don't have anything on the computer except the OS at this point.